# Apache2 https redirect configuration

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, apache2

How can I confgure my apache2 server to redirect on specific URL to https?

Base directory on server should be supported by http, for example  `example.com/*`, but all request to directory `example.com/priv/*` should be automatically redirect to https.

My server is configured to works on http or https, but i can't automativally redirect to https in specific directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *mod_rewrite*.

First, create an `.htaccess` file which has to be in your document `root` folder.
Then, put this code into it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^priv(?:/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note: you could also put this code directly in your Apache configuration file instead, that's up to you.
Make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled

Comment: that works but something is with https configuration, default page works on http only when URI is ened with double slash (http://example.com//), when i use default page like: www.example.com then server redirect to https